# Search result items goes to display form intead of opening the file

Tags: search-results, crawling

PDF and other office filetypes are installed through Search Services. Never had this issue before. All of sudden, when I or user click on the search result it goes to display item form. but used to be able to open any type of files (well, office, pic, pdf, etc.)

I know one option is to reset, re-index and full crawl. That's my last option if I really have to do this again. (just went through re-indexing about a month ago)

Thanks
MB

Comment: Do I have to have "IsDocument=1" for a given scope in order for links to open the document (office, image or pdf) instead of Disp.aspx form? Anyone out there can help me think differently. Can't seem to pinpoint the issue here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're on Sharepoint 2010 and NOT 2013. If you are on 2010, make sure you install PDF iFilter 9 for Sharepoint Search.  Sharepoint 2013 has PDF iFilter installed by default (woo hoo!)  Make sure you follow the directions exactly as listed in this article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2293357

Most common mistakes:

1)  Not restarting the Sharepoint Search service

2)  Not restarting every server in the farm for the Registry entry to take affect

3)  Not adding "pdf" to the filetypes in the CORRECT Search Service application that they are using.

Comment: PDF iFilter is installed. We are on SP 2010. Search center for another site collection renders all the files (pdf, office, etc) normally meaning file opens instead of display page.

Comment: Maybe try resetting the index and re-crawling .  It could be that maybe the other site collection which works fine was crawled after the iFilter was installed?  Also make sure that the URL for your PDFs appear with a .pdf extension in the crawl log itself...if it doesn't then you can bet the iFilter didn't do it's work on those files.  Clearing the index should take care if that scenario

Comment: iFilter for pdf was installed long time ago. It's happening with all file types. File icons for respective file types do show up in the search result. I did a reset, re-index about a month ago and that broke one of the search center. Basically, not all search center within the web application are affected. About 3 of the search center are affected. 5 other search center working normally.